# 'int' object is not subscriptable PYTHON

Tags: python

When the loop starts the second time this makes an error:

```
 33 for i in range(1,len(t)):

 ---> 34   aux=t[i][2]
      35   aux2=t[i][4]
      36   empresa=t[i][0]      TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

```
for i in range(1,len(t)):
  aux=t[i][2]
  aux2=t[i][4]
  empresa=t[i][0]
  fecha=t[i][1]
  mails=aux.split(',')
  facturas=aux2.split(',')
  for t in range(0,len(mails)):
    print(mails[t])
    server.sendmail(msg['From'], mails[t], msg.as_string())
  print('se mando la linea '+str(empresa))
```

Please help me

Comment: What is `t`? Can you show us where you define it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, you are renaming your variable `t` which was supposed to be a list or an array to an integer. Hence, the first loop iteration when `t[i][2]` or any list reference to `t` works fine, however, when it comes to the **for loop** part in the first loop, `t` is changed to integer type, hence, in the second loop iteration, it says 'int' object is not subscriptable.
You can change `t` in the for loop below to another variable name.

```
for i in range(1,len(t)):
  aux=t[i][2]
  aux2=t[i][4]
  empresa=t[i][0]
  fecha=t[i][1]
  mails=aux.split(',')
  facturas=aux2.split(',')
  for t in range(0,len(mails)):   --> You are changing t here from list to int
    print(mails[t])
    server.sendmail(msg['From'], mails[t], msg.as_string())
  print('se mando la linea '+str(empresa))
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 9 `print(mails[t])`,
your variable t is overwritten as int because of the inner for-loop. It is not the iterator anymore. Thus for the second iteration of the upper(outer) for-loop, it does not remain iterator.
As @Anurag said, just use different variable name instead of **t** for the inner loop on line 8 and inside the second for-loop